# How to display 'InValid' records depending on, if the latest record is validated?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

**Goal**

Retrieve `InValid` records but with some complexity. Let me explain.

Taking a look at this output: There is an `InValid` record for `ItemId` of `1`.

[image]

Using the query below, I am able to see `InValid` records - to display to the user this Item needs to be Re-Checked.

```
SELECT * FROM `Records` WHERE IsValid = 0;
```

**Problem**

This is where I am stuck.

In the Red is the `InValid` record, recorded on the `28-06-2021`. The next day, `29-09-2021` the `ItemId` is now a `Valid` record.

[image]

But using this query below is not relevant anymore, as it will show me the records that are still `Invalid`. Even though the record has been validated the next day.

```
SELECT * FROM `Records` WHERE IsValid = 0;
```

**My idea to solve this problem (See Edit 1 below, for further details to this solution)**

My idea would be to create a Trigger that will check if `today's record is valid`, `if it is valid`, then `Update all the items to true where date is before today`. From here, I can use the simple query above to see `InValid` records.

Also, I thought of creating a `History table` and a trigger to see what actions have been performed on the `Records table`.

**Question**

I am not sure if my idea is appropriate to solve my problem, creating a trigger to update all previous records does not seem the records are valid at all. But, my history table will show me valid values.

Is there a query I can use and avoid creating any triggers or it's best to go with my solution?

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
-- Base
CREATE TABLE `Items` (
  Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ItemName VARCHAR(30));

CREATE TABLE `Records` (
  Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  ItemId INT NOT NULL,
  IsValid BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (ItemId) REFERENCES `Items`(Id));
                                  
-- History
CREATE TABLE `Records_History` LIKE `Records`;
                                          
ALTER TABLE `Records_History`
    MODIFY COLUMN Id INT NOT NULL,
    DROP PRIMARY KEY,
    ADD Action VARCHAR(8) DEFAULT 'insert' FIRST;

CREATE TRIGGER Records_AfterInsert
    AFTER INSERT ON `Records` FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO `Records_History` SELECT 'insert', d.*
    FROM `Records` AS d WHERE d.Id = NEW.Id;
                                             
-- Insert Records
INSERT INTO `Items`
    (ItemName)
VALUES
  ('Item 1'),
  ('Item 2');
                                          
 INSERT INTO `Records`
    (Date, ItemId, IsValid)
 VALUES
   ('2021-09-28', 1, 0),
   ('2021-09-28', 2, 1),
   ('2021-09-29', 1, 1),
   ('2021-09-29', 2, 1);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select * from `Records`;
```

| Id | Date | ItemId | IsValid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-09-28 00:00:00 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2021-09-28 00:00:00 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2021-09-29 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 2021-09-29 00:00:00 | 2 | 1 |

---

**Query #2**

```
select * from `Records_History`;
```

| Action | Id | Date | ItemId | IsValid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| insert | 1 | 2021-09-28 00:00:00 | 1 | 0 |
| insert | 2 | 2021-09-28 00:00:00 | 2 | 1 |
| insert | 3 | 2021-09-29 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 |
| insert | 4 | 2021-09-29 00:00:00 | 2 | 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/671pBABN8hvFnZMFdQ3LXV/0)

**Edit 1**

Unfortunately my solution is not an option. As I will hit this error:

```
Tried my solution: Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'Records' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function
```

This basically means: I have a chance of causing an infinite loop.

Comment: How about you select the rows that have the maximum Date for each ItemId and then see if those are valid or not? I'd probably go with an audit table, where each time you insert, update or delete a record in the main table, you put those values into your audit trail with a timestamp. Then you can keep your main table with just the most recent record only.

Comment: What do you need exactly? Do you need a working SQL query that will update the isValid column of the same ItemId to True when isValid column of today record is True? Or do you need a solution that will execute the SQL query automatically everyday?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done to achieve my goal:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));

CREATE TABLE `Items` (
  Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ItemName VARCHAR(30));

INSERT INTO `Items`
    (ItemName)
VALUES
  ('Item 1'),
  ('Item 2');

CREATE TABLE `Records` (
  Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  ItemId INT NOT NULL,
  IsValid BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (ItemId) REFERENCES `Items`(Id));
  
 INSERT INTO `Records`
    (Date, ItemId, IsValid)
 VALUES
   ('2021-09-28', 1, 1),
   ('2021-09-28', 2, 1),
   ('2021-09-29', 1, 0),
   ('2021-09-29', 2, 1),
   ('2021-09-30', 1, 1),
   ('2021-09-30', 2, 1),
   ('2021-10-01', 1, 0),
   ('2021-10-01', 2, 1);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM Records a WHERE IsValid = 0 AND ItemId NOT IN (
       SELECT ItemId FROM Records b WHERE IsValid = 1 AND b.Date >= a.Date
    ) GROUP BY ItemId;
```

| Id | Date | ItemId | IsValid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 2021-10-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 0 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/671pBABN8hvFnZMFdQ3LXV/0)